# Can we execute everytime a function/piece of code before each API call in VertX v2 java backend?

Tags: java, vert.x

In VertX V2, when we call any API a handler class is called and handle method in it is executed.

I need to execute a piece of code to check whether a parameter is present in Request URL or not like we do in Junit testing using @Before, @BeforeClass, @BeforeEach, @BeforeAll.

Is there any similar way in vertx present?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to provide API specific pre-handler or pre handler common to all APIs?

If you are looking for API specific, then **No**, vert.x do not have anything such.

But if you want to declare request filter/pre-handler common to all requests,
then you can do something like below,

```
mainRouter.route().handler(CommonReqFilter::doFilter);
// your API call handler should be here
```

And then calling `routingContext.next()` from within `CommonReqFilter::doFilter` once pre-processing/validation is done.
NOTE: This needs to be declared before registering actual API call handler to `mainRouter`

```
next()
```

will call next handler, which is you registered to handle API call.